# ReferenceManyFields / ReferenceArrayField Combination

Tags: admin-on-rest

I know the usage of both the components is clearly different, `ReferenceManyFields` used to make `request` to certain resource by filtering the `target` with the current `id`.
`ReferenceArrayFields` used to make `request` to certain resource by filtering the referenced `id` using the `source` that contain some `ids`.

`ReferenceManyFields` has `target` props, `ReferenceArrayFields` has `source` props. Is there any way to send the request based on the `target` and `source` ?

Here is my code..

```
export const ApplicationEdit = (props) => {
return  (
    <Edit {...props} >
        <SimpleForm>
            <ReferenceManyFields reference="applications" target="customer_id" source="costumer_id" addLabel={true} label="Application History">
                <Datagrid>
                    <TextField source="id" />
                    <DateField source="date" />
                    <TextField source="amount" />
                    <TextField source="status" />
                    <TextField source="customer_id" />
                </Datagrid>
            </ReferenceManyFields>

        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

}

Comment: Can you explain your usecase ?

Comment: I have `ApplicationShow` that show details of an application made by users, inside `ApplicationShow`, I need to show the related user's past application history to a gridlist.

Comment: @Gildas anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share your resources definitions ?

Comment: Please wait, I will post it here

Comment: @Gildas any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible currently but it looks like a valid use case to me. I'll see if we can address this in next version